# Problem with consuming Axis2 webservice in .net POST request returns empty

Tags: c#, wcf, soap-client

I'm tying to consume a specific method from a webservice and i keep receiving an empty reply (sometimes internal error message).

The webservice can be found at http://test3.alignetsac.com/bizlinks-ws/BizlinksInvokerImplService/BizlinksInvokerImplService.wsdl

The method i'm trying to consume is called invokeBizlinksConsult.
I'm supposed to use Preemptive Authentication and send the command inside CDATA tags.

I was even provided a SOAPUI example that works fine, sometimes, other times i get an Internal Error (image below).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGgHB.jpg

I created a Service Reference to generate the classes and ran into the issue while testing the method.

Simple console application i created to test it (edited to add authentication header)

```
wsClient.BizlinksInvokerClient invoker = new wsClient.BizlinksInvokerClient();
invoker.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "usr";
invoker.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";
invoker.ClientCredentials.SupportInteractive = true;
string command = "";
command += "<![CDATA[<ConsultCmd><parameter name=\"idAdquiriente\" value =\"20101337261\" /></ConsultCmd>]]>";
using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(invoker.InnerChannel)){
       var hrmp = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
       hrmp.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(invoker.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + invoker.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
       OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = hrmp;
       var resp = invoker.invokeBizlinksConsult(command);
       Console.WriteLine(resp);
}
```

The problem is resp is empty at the end.

Fiddler result from SOAPUI
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxt4m.jpg

Fiddler result from console app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGMLX.jpg

Things i have tried:

- Using Web Reference instead of Service Reference-> same issue.
- Try/catch doesn't throw any exceptions.
- Removing the CDATA tag -> Gives internal error in SOAPUI, empty response in console app.
- Sending empty command -> Returns empty body in SOAPUI, empty response in console app.

EDIT: Authentication header wasn't showing in fiddler when i tested my connection, but it did show in SOAPUI so i manually added it.
Now the Fiddler inspector from the console app is closer to SOAPUI's
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBZN7.jpg

But now the SOAPAction being sent by the console app doesn't match the one in SOAPUI, which in turn does match the one in the WSDL file.

WSDL action is:

<soap:operation soapAction=""/>

Fiddler shows i'm sending:
SOAPAction: "http://ws.bizlinks.com/BizlinksInvoker/invokeBizlinksConsultRequest"

Fiddler SOAPUI:
SOAPAction: ""

I think the problem is the SOAPAction being sent doesn't match the one in the .wsdl. So how do i remove the SOAPAction the console app is sending or how do i change it to SOAPAction = "" at runtime?

Comment: Is the server-side a WCF service?

Comment: Found the problem: The CDATA tag, which is mandatory in SOAPUI, was the responsible. Removing it from the command string solved the issue.